Tip.statusUpdates doesn't fire on event donation
I have a tip that's supposed to be shown after a certain event:
extension Tips {
    static let somethingHappened = Tip.Event(id: "somethingHappened")
}

struct TestTip: Tip {
    let title = Text("Test tip")
    let message = Text("This is a description")

    var rules: [Rule] {
        #Rule(Tips.somethingHappened) { $0.donations.count > 0 }
    }
}

I would like to present this tip when its status becomes .available. To do this, I'm observing statusUpdates in a task:
tipStatusObserverTask = Task { [tip, weak self] in
    print("observing \(tip.id)")

    for await status in tip.statusUpdates {
        guard let self, !Task.isCancelled else {
            return
        }

        print("tip status: \(status)")

        if case .available = status {
            print("will present \(tip.id)")
            displayTip()
        }
    }

    print("done observing \(tip.id)")
}

then I'm donating the event on a button press:
@objc func didPressButton() {
    Tips.somethingHappened.sendDonation {
        print("donated Tips.somethingHappened")
    }
}

The event is donated, but statusUpdates doesn't fire, so the tip never gets shown. The tip appears after I restart the app. What's happening? What am I doing wrong?
statusUpdates fires just fine if the rule is based on a @Parameter change, so I would expect this approach to work for event-based rules.
Here's a project that reproduces the issue in case anyone wants to try: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/085FxcgTPStDSSPoXwh7dx1pQ#TipKitTest
Update: This is likely a bug, I have filed a radar: FB16040974

I believe you're missing configurations. Try to put these code before setting up tipStatusObserverTask
private func setupTips() throws {
    try Tips.resetDatastore()
    try Tips.configure()
}

Edit: As you mentioned, it could be an iOS 18 bug. I've read the release notes and update for TipKit. However, there is no information about how Apple changes the #Rule or something. So, fire a report is the only option, I guess.

I omitted this bit in my question, but in the project I attached I do this in app delegate, so the problem is somewhere else.

Oh, that's weird. I've downloaded your project and I cannot reproduce on both simulator iOS 17.5 and real device iPhone 15 iOS 17.5.1

You're right, the issue is not reproduced on iOS 17, so this is probably a regression in iOS 18. I will file a radar. In the meantime, you can update your answer so I can accept it.

Oh thanks, btw, can you attach the ticket issue? @AndriiChernenko

FB16040974: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/16040974

I thought the ticket was public but seems like it was sticked with your account. Anw, thanks for sharing.
